# Difference between making a nodejs app on server OS and normal OS

Tags: linux, node.js, centos

This might be a little bit of stupid question, but I would like to know better.

I've been doing some small projects with NodeJS in my PC with Windows10, normally, using express as framework, some modules, testing the app on Chrome connecting to localhost:3000... But recently, I've been ask to install CentOS Linux OS and make some project overthere (application that count words submitted on a form). I know that server OS is better and can have some configuration to provide services for your applications; what things should I set up on this linux server OS for this project? Should I use the same ports? Cause I don't think I have to make just the same steps I would do if I were building the app in Windows 10...

I hope my question is clear, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between server and desktop OS is that server OS has better support for multi-core processors, virtualization, memory management, etc. It shouldn't make much difference for your applications, especially on higher level languages like Java, JavaScript (NodeJS), Ruby, PHP...

So you should only install NodeJS like this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

And upload your application to server and run. If you use database, you must install it too, but from your question I don't think you do use anything more.

When you have a lot of different dependencies, you can take a look at Docker. It's a packaging and deployment system for applications, and It will help you to pack everything you need in one single image. That way you can be 100% sure that your application will run anywhere.
[You can take a look here](https://www.docker.com/)

Comment: Got it! But what you mean by "upload your application to server"? I'm using VirtualBox to simulate the server OS btw. Thanks for answer!

PD: Knew about Docker, but is good idea in this case :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can try some Platform-as-a-Service, e.g. OpenShift (https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-overview.html). This way your server is already set up with all best practices and you only copy your code.

Comment: Hmmm problem is that I have to use CentOS! Is there a way to make something similar with this os? thanks @PavolPitonak

Comment: @ArtanisAce If your CentOS machine is on a remote machine you would use something like FTP or SFTP (FTP over SSH) to upload your application files. Since your machine is virtual machine on your local computer, you can even mount a directory from your host computer. That way you can literally copy/paste files in a shared folder and it will be visible inside of your VM.

Comment: thanks @DoubleM will do that! And should I make some server configuration to allow connections right? If they sent me this task, to create the app within an OS  server, is to run the app from their location while my computer has the server role right?

Comment: @ArtanisAce Well that's more a networking issue than software problem, but yes, basically you have to configure your VirtualBox machine to act as a NAT device so ports to your vitual machine will be opened to outside world. Also you will probably need to configure port forwarding on your home router (ADSL, etc.) so all incoming requests are redirected to your machine. And make sure to give them your **public** IP address, you can find it here: [What's my IP](http://www.whatsmyip.org/)